# Can GraphAPI be used to create item to list using SPFx, even if Current Loged-In user have have only Read Permission on list?

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, spfx-webparts, microsoft-graph

With SPFx can item be created in a list using GraphAPI if User have only "Read" permission on list? Will granting delegate Permission to SPFx solution with Sites.ReadWrite,Site.All will work?

Answer (score 0):

No.
You can parse the bearer token at the time of the request, and you will find that user permissions are actually at work.
This is the analysis of the bearer token with a successful request.
[image]
You could parse the token [here](https://jwt.io/).

Comment: Just confused at this place is - when we are granting appropriate permission using web-apipermission in package-solution.json file. It basically creating an Azure AD application in background. But confused why unable to process the request when we have already granting permission to create item?

Comment: In such case when we add webapipermissionRequests in packag-solution.json file, and try to get the client object. On what context it will be executing the request ?

Comment: @user27178   Use the Azure AD app registration process.  It basically gives you an application ‘password’ whereby the app can be invoked by authorized users in your org.

Answer (score 0):

One approach could be to call an Azure function from your SPFx component, however the update will be in the context of the App not the user.

Comment: Or I can align a MS flow to create an item in list with trigger point as when an http request is received. And call the flow from spfx. This flow will be published using service account.